# Is there a way to get the current UIEvent being handled?

Tags: iphone, events, touch

I'm working in a class that is a delegate of another class; this other class is in a third-party library that I'd like to avoid changing if at all possible.

The original class is handling a -touchesEnded event, and is delegating responsibility to me, but it doesn't pass the UIEvent itself to me.  Is there a way to get a handle to the current event in progress?  It's a double-tap handler, and all that is passed to me is the view being touched, and the point at which the touch occurred.  I want to know exactly how many touches are involved in the event.

Thanks!
randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the original 3rd-party view and override `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` in that subclass.

You can also subclass UIApplication and override its `-sendEvent:` method to capture all (public) events.